# slicing a numpy array using indices from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am going crazy trying to slice a 2D array according to values from another array:

```
# array of integer values:
aa = np.random.randint(500, 600, size=(5,5)

array([[574, 550, 548, 545, 551],
       [547, 539, 539, 502, 528],
       [503, 530, 582, 567, 505],
       [590, 504, 510, 578, 525],
       [530, 548, 501, 580, 583]])

# array of indices:
ab = np.random.randint(4, size=(5,5))

array([[3, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 2, 1, 3],
       [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

What I want to return is a 2D subarray of *aa*, wherever *ab* is 1.  But the closest I can get is:

```
aa[ab==1]

array([545, 551, 502, 582, 590, 578, 501, 580])
```

I'm always getting a 1D array as an output... How can I get my output array in the same dimensions as the  original one?

EDIT:
Sorry, I should have specified the expected output:

```
array([[545, 551],
       [502],
       [582],
       [590, 578],
       [501, 580]])
```

I also picked a poor example for the index array *ab*, it will always have the same number of 1s per row - so the output array would have the dimensions (5,2).

Comment: Please show the expected output for the values above.

Comment: If it is the same dimensions as the original, what should be at the elements where `ab!=1` do you just want to fill with `0`?

Comment: If the suggestions from @CoryKramer is what you want, all you need is: `numpy.where(ab == 1, aa, 0)`

Comment: If you want a masked array, that's easy too, but you need to invert the logic: `numpy.ma.masked_array(data=aa, mask=(ab!=1), fill_value=0)`

Comment: Technically that's not `(5,2)`, but `(5,)`.

Comment: You can't have ragged arrays as such. Masked array may be OK though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2D array of numbers of varying shape (one or two numbers per row) isn't, to the best of my knowledge and common sense, supported by `numpy`. If you try to instantiate the array that is your expected result, you'll hit issues:

```
In[23]: np.array([[545, 551],
   [502],
   [582],
   [590, 578],
   [501, 580]])
Out[23]: 
array([list([545, 551]), list([502]), list([582]), list([590, 578]),
   list([501, 580])], dtype=object) # Note the data type.

In[24]: np.array([[545, 551],
   [502],
   [582],
   [590, 578],
   [501, 580]],dtype=float) # Force float.
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

If you're sure that you'll always have an equal and known number of `1`s in `ab`, you could do the following:

```
In[2]: aa = np.array([[574, 550, 548, 545, 551],
   [547, 539, 539, 502, 528],
   [503, 530, 582, 567, 505],
   [590, 504, 510, 578, 525],
   [530, 548, 501, 580, 583]])

In[3]: ab = np.array([[3, 0, 2, 1, 1], # N.B. edited w.r.t. your example to have two 1s per row.
   [3, 1, 2, 1, 3],
   [0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
   [1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
   [3, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

In[4]: aa[ab==1].reshape((-1,2))
Out[4]: 
array([[545, 551],
   [539, 502],
   [530, 582],
   [590, 578],
   [501, 580]])
```

If you don't *a priori* know how many `1`s there are in every row of `ab`, you could simply do the following:

```
In[5]: aa[ab==1].reshape((-1,sum(ab[0,:]==1)))
Out[5]: 
array([[545, 551],
   [539, 502],
   [530, 582],
   [590, 578],
   [501, 580]])
```

Does this answer your question? Or are you looking for something more like the [`MaskedArray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray) suggested in comments?

Comment: This, especially the last part, is what I was looking for.  Thanks @Aleksander for working out the `reshape()` trickery for me!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, this is the best and shortest way I could come up with:

```
ac = np.array(list(zip(aa.ravel(),ab.ravel())), dtype=('i4,i4')).reshape(aa.shape)
ad= list(filter(None, [[i[0] for i in line if i[1] == 1] for line in ac]))
ad
```

Example:

```
aa = np.random.randint(500, 600, size=(5,5))

array([[560, 518, 569, 508, 582],
       [536, 556, 564, 523, 559],
       [501, 526, 596, 586, 567],
       [586, 536, 561, 503, 551],
       [500, 537, 508, 585, 556]])

ab = np.random.randint(4, size=(5,5))

array([[2, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 2],
       [3, 0, 2, 3, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 0]])

#Zipping both arrays to create a tuple
ac = np.array(list(zip(aa.ravel(),ab.ravel())), dtype=('i4,i4')).reshape(aa.shape)
ac

array([[(560, 2), (518, 2), (569, 3), (508, 2), (582, 3)],
       [(536, 0), (556, 0), (564, 1), (523, 0), (559, 1)],
       [(501, 2), (526, 1), (596, 2), (586, 0), (567, 2)],
       [(586, 3), (536, 0), (561, 2), (503, 3), (551, 2)],
       [(500, 0), (537, 2), (508, 2), (585, 1), (556, 0)]])

#List comprehension to filter for elements where ab == 1 and remove empty lists
ad= list(filter(None, [[i[0] for i in line if i[1] == 1] for line in ac]))
ad

[[564, 559], [526], [585]]
```

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The number of matches per row of `ab` vary:

```
In [246]: ab==1                                                                               
Out[246]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False]])
In [247]: (ab==1).sum(axis=1)                                                                 
Out[247]: array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
In [248]: aa[ab==1]                                                                           
Out[248]: array([545, 551, 502, 582, 590, 578, 501, 580])
```

`numpy` indexing docs is quite clear that when the boolean indexing array matches the argument, the result is 1d.  It can't in the general case maintain the original number of dimensions.  In special cases you could reshape the result to 2d (but not this).

To get the ragged list of matches that you want, you have to iterate by rows:

```
In [249]: [a[b] for a,b in zip(aa, ab==1)]                                                    
Out[249]: 
[array([545, 551]),
 array([502]),
 array([582]),
 array([590, 578]),
 array([501, 580])]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

> If obj.ndim == x.ndim, x[obj] returns a 1-dimensional array filled with the elements of x corresponding to the True values of obj. The search order will be row-major, C-style.

Alternatives mentioned in the comments:

```
In [250]: np.where(ab==1, aa,0)                                                               
Out[250]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0, 545, 551],
       [  0,   0,   0, 502,   0],
       [  0,   0, 582,   0,   0],
       [590,   0,   0, 578,   0],
       [  0,   0, 501, 580,   0]])
In [251]: np.ma.masked_array(aa, ab!=1)                                                       
Out[251]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --, 545, 551],
        [--, --, --, 502, --],
        [--, --, 582, --, --],
        [590, --, --, 578, --],
        [--, --, 501, 580, --]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True, False, False,  True]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

The `aa[ab==1]` indexing is equivalent to indexing with the two arrays derived with `nonzero` (aka `where`):

```
In [252]: np.nonzero(ab==1)                                                                   
Out[252]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]), array([3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3]))
In [253]: aa[_]                                                                               
Out[253]: array([545, 551, 502, 582, 590, 578, 501, 580])
```

The shape of [253] matches the shape of the arrays in [252].